# What is JMSType used for?

Tags: jms

What is JMSType used for?  Can it be used to define the message payload?  For example, the payload might be for adding a product and the JMSType could be AddProduct.

Answer (score 11):

JMS Specification says "*The `JMSType` header field contains a message type identifier supplied by a
client when a message is sent. Some JMS providers use a message repository that contains the definitions of messages sent by applications. The type header field may reference a message’s
definition in the provider’s repository. JMS does not define a standard message definition repository, nor does it define a naming policy for the definitions it contains.*"

In effect, you can set `JMSType` to a value of your choice but it is suggested you make sure every application that runs on your JMS provider use the same values for `JMSType`.